# JAXB @XmlElements to have minOccurs = 1

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

So I want to have a list to be annotated with @XmlElements like the following

```
@XmlElements(
        {
            @XmlElement(name = "Apple", type = Apple.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "Orange", type = Orange.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "Mango", type = Mango.class)
        }
)
public List<Fruit> getEntries() {
        return fruitList;
}
```

I am wondering whether there is a way to enforce the list to contain at least 1 element, because right now, the xsd looks like

```
<xs:complexType name="fruitList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Apple" type="tns:apple"/>
        <xs:element name="Orange" type="tns:orange"/>
        <xs:element name="Mango" type="tns:mango"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: You mean a schema generated from your java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that Apple, Orange, and Mango are subclasses of Fruit you may want to annotate the `entries` property with `@XmlElementRef` which corresponds to substitution groups in XML schema, rather than `@XmlElements` which corresponds to the concept of choice.

```
@XmlElementRef
public List<Fruit> getEntries() {
        return fruitList;
}
```

This assumes that the Apple, Orange, and Mango classes extend the Fruit class, and are annotated with `@XmlRootElement`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Apple extends Fruit {
   ...
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

Comment: how is this going to help me in enforcing at least 1 element in the list?

Comment: @denniss - You are correct in that `@XmlElementRef` will also produce `minOccurs="0"`.  I was simply offering it as an alternative (simpler) mapping for the property, assuming inheritance was involved.  JAXB is more focused on mapping to XML rather than schema constraints, so there may not be a way to get the `minOccurs='1'` that you are after.  You can always modify the XML schema that is generated by JAXB.

Answer (score 15):

I suggest to check:

```
@XmlElements(
    {
        @XmlElement(name = "Apple", type = Apple.class, required = true),
        @XmlElement(name = "Orange", type = Orange.class, required = true),
        @XmlElement(name = "Mango", type = Mango.class, required = true)
    }
)
```

Comment: Was looking for a solution to the problem as well, and this one does the trick. Generated XML omits `minOccurs` attribute which translates into the default (=1).