# Force minOccurs to 1 in a xsd:choice with JAXB

Tags: jaxb, xjc

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137968/xjc-java-class-generation-for-xschoice-element-which-is-not-unbounded/12917183#12917183) I've been able to create a proper choice with JAXB but when jaxb generates the Java classes from the schema it generates the choice element with minOccurs equals to 0 instead of 1 which would be more appropiate.

Anyone knows who to solve that?. If I [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022690/jaxb-xmlelements-to-have-minoccurs-1) the required attribute in the classes that have been generated then I force to set minOccurs to 1, but I'd like to do this from the XSD instead of modifying directly the java classes.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022690/jaxb-xmlelements-to-have-minoccurs-1#6953607) from @jrq85 worked for me.